# Update row column without collapse rowDetail in ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, angular5, ngx-datatable

I use ngx-datatable to create a table with rowDetail in my Angular5 app.

[Example code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvwhus?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

There is a button call "Austin growup" , after clicking , the Austin's age will change and update table through `this.rows = [...this.rows]` in function `updateTable()`.

But when I click button after expanding the detail row, the table will refresh and collapse all the rowDetail.

I think the problem is `this.rows = [...this.rows]`. I believe that will refresh whole table.

so...is there any way to dynamically update one row's value without collapse rowDetail (or without whole table refresh).

Any suggestion will be help, thank you.

Comment: no any suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

i have forked your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aoghss). The modified code to retain expanded rows on updating the the rows is

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  @ViewChild('myTable') table: any;
  // to hold expanded row IDs
  expandedId=[];

  rows = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Austin', gender: 'Male', age: 20},
    { id: 1, name: 'Dany', gender: 'Male', age: 30},
    { id: 2, name: 'Molly', gender: 'Female', age: 40},
  ];

   constructor() {}



  toggleExpandRow(row) {
    console.log('Toggled Expand Row!', row);
    this.table.rowDetail.toggleExpandRow(row);
    // adding the expanded row to row id on expanding and removing row id on collapse.
    const index=this.expandedId.indexOf(row.id);
    if(index > -1)
      this.expandedId.splice(index,1);
    else{
      this.expandedId.push(row.id);
    }
  }

  onDetailToggle(event) {
    console.log('Detail Toggled', event);
  }

  updateTable(){
    this.rows[0].age = this.rows[0].age + 1;
    this.rows = [...this.rows];
  // expanding the rows upon updating the row values.
     setTimeout(()=> {
       this.expand();
     },100);
  }
// method to toggle the rows in expandedId
expand(){
    this.table.rowDetail.collapseAllRows();
    for(var i=0;i<this.rows.length;i++){
      if(this.expandedId.indexOf(this.rows[i].id) > -1){
        this.table.rowDetail.toggleExpandRow(this.rows[i])
      }
    }
}

  ngOnInit(){

  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I know you way is to reopen it again, but in my real case , when the row detail open, It will call an API to get some data, so reopen will cause API calling again which I dont' want it happen.  So that's why I don't want the whole table refresh. Still thanks for your reply : )

Answer (score 0):

*It's too late, but hope this can help someone else...*

I changed your code and added one button on grid says "Growup"

you can check demo here: https://angular-f8e5ed.stackblitz.io

check code(fork from your code): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8e5ed

added one column in grid:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Action" >
          <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            <a style="cursor: pointer; color: chocolate; font-style: italic;" (click)="onEditClick(row)">Growup</a>
          </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

function which called via click on growup from grid:

```
onEditClick(row) {
    ++row.age; 
  }
```

This way you can manage/update data on a particular row without reloading/refresh entire ngx rows each time.